# Get windows sharing equal screen space to front

Tags: windows-7

Windows seven
Enerprise Edition Service pack 1..

I use Win+left_arrow
and Win+right_arrow key very often.

Say window A and
window B are now sharing the screen equally.

And I switch to a
maximized (using entire screen space) window C, and then a maximised (using entire screen space) window E.

Window A still uses
the left half of the screen and window B still uses the right half of the
screen if I make either of them an active window.So I have to first click on
window A from the task bar and then Window B. THat is how I again get to view
the content inside window A and window B simultaneously.

Question: How do I
get both Windows A and B to share the screen equally again with a shortcut?
When currently I have C or D as an active maximised window

Note: When I say
full screen I am referring to Alt + space+X and not the F11 on browsers that
makes the address bar go away.

Comment: By "full screen" you clearly mean "maximised". Regardless there's no in-built way to activate multiple background windows simultaneously.